# facebook chatbot localization of greeting message not working

Tags: localization, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm trying to localize the greeting message in my facebook chatbot. Here is the curl command I sent to do this:
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "greeting":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "text":"Hi {{user_first_name}}"
    },
    {
      "locale":"ar_AR",
      "text":"مرحبا {{user_first_name}}"

    }
  ] 
}'  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=MY_TOKEN_HERE"`

This command succeeded.

When my smartphone's language is set to english I get the english one normally. However, when I switch my phone to arabic, I get question marks instead of the arabic text saying 'مرحبا'.

I would like to know why I'm getting question marks even though my text is in arabic. What I ultimately want to do (If possible) is to set the default text to arabic text so it **always** shows that even if the smartphone's language is set to english or something else.

P.S. I got the arabic `locale` string representation from [here](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly escape non-ASCII characters.

`{"text":"\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627 {{user_first_name}}"}` would be the *proper* JSON representation of an array containing one element with the key `text` and the content `مرحبا {{user_first_name}}`

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! if anyone wants a quick way to convert his text to unicode he/she can use this website: http://www.mobilefish.com/services/unicode_escape_sequence_converter/unicode_escape_sequence_converter.php